# Is there a way to find out Resource group for a given VM and then find out details of VM in Azure using Python sdk

Tags: python, azure, sdk, virtual-machine

I refereed to various articles here,but not found exact solution

Is there a way to find out Resource group for a given VM and then find out details of VM in Azure using Python sdk

can some one point me to right example ?

What I am trying to do is

- input private ip of azure vm
- need to find out resource group in which this azure machine
- then it should get vm details of above vm under that resource management group

Comment: Regarding "a given vm", do you have the vm name or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just know the name of the vm, the only way is that list all the vms via `list_all()` method -> then pick up the specified vm via it's name.

Note: the risk here is that, the vm's name is not unique across different resource groups. So it's possible that there're more than one vm with the same same in different resource groups. You should take care of this case.

The sample code:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'xxxx'
VM_NAME = 'xxxx'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id='xxxxx',
    secret='xxxxx',
    tenant='xxxxx'
)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credentials=credentials,
    subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)

vms = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()

myvm_resource_group=""

for vm in vms:
    if vm.name == VM_NAME:
        print(vm.id)

        #the vm.id is always in this format: 
        #'/subscriptions/your_subscription_id/resourceGroups/your_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/your_vm_name'
        #so you can split it into list, and the resource_group_name's index is always 4 in this list.
        temp_id_list=vm.id.split('/')
        myvm_resource_group=temp_id_list[4]

print("**********************!!!!!!!!!!")

print("the vm test0's resource group is: " + myvm_resource_group)

# now you know the vm name and it's resourcegroup, you can use other methods,
# like compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name, vm_name) to do any operations for this vm.
```

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: Hi Ivan Yang, it helps. actually now I need to fecth, tag information, instance information like cpu, type etc and also disc information, root and swap etc

Comment: @asp, now you can get the vm instance, then just try to find if there are such properties/method(like vm.tag or vm.type etc.) of this vm instance. And if you cannot figure it out, please @ me in the comment. I'd like to work on it.

Comment: Let me try , definitely let u know if I need help..

Comment: i am trying for instance details, but i am not getting all values, referred to documentation for describing instance but not able to find full fledged info.I am looking at following items to be output as json format for a VM.. `resource groupname,status,Operating system,Size,Location ,Public Ip Address,VirtualNetwork/subnet
Availability Zone,Private Ip,Static IP,VM Generation, Size: Size,vcpu,RAM, Disk:OS Disk,Azure disk encryption,Data Disks Volumes::Name,Size,Storage Account,Ecnryption Volume Tags: its Key and value Backup:Backup pre-check,Last backup status,Backu poliy:its name needed`

Comment: is there a describe vm kind of coomand which will give above attributes

Comment: @asp, could you please submit a new issue in stackoverflow? and then let me know the link:).

Comment: as requested here the link new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62828586/how-to-azure-important-attribute-values-for-a-given-vm-in-json-format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217585/discussion-between-asp-and-ivan-yang).

Comment: @asp, do you know how to debug the python script in `vs code`? It seems that we need  to write a very long python code to cover all your needs. If you know how to debug, I can guide you how to get all of these values, and it's quite easy.

Comment: yeah, i have pycharm, shall do, ideally i can have seperate snippets for each category